# Jenkins Github pull request builder security warning

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, pull-request

I am running a Jenkins server on Amazon EC2. I integrated our Github account into Jenkins and I want to run Rails rpsec tests on each pull request i.e. pull the code from the target branch and put it through Rspec.

I see a lot of tutorials about the Github pull request builder, but most of them do not take into consideration this issue. I found one, which said that we should not use the plugin prior to the version 1.40.0. My version is 1.42.0 and it still shows this issue.

[image]

The warning says *GitHub access tokens stored in in build.xml*.
My question is about the severeness of this problem and is it safe to use it, because it seems that it is the way most popular plugin for this kind of task.

Comment: did you find any answer for your question?

Comment: I did not find any yet.